# Unable to remove navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem in Three20

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, three20

Consider the following code in my `TTTableViewController`, I have

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(Add:)] autorelease];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;   
}
```

I was able to add the right button, but failed to remove the left button.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot [super ViewDidLoad];